# Datanode is not showing up on hitting jps command

Tags: hadoop

I am newbie in hadoop i have setup multinode cluster but when i hit jps command on master node it shows only namenode not datanode and when i paste this url 'Master:50070' it shows `no live node` due to which i am unable to copy data from my local system into hdfs it throws this error

```
hduser@oodles-Latitude-3540:~$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/oodles/input/test /tmp
15/06/28 16:27:56 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /tmp/test._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1549)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:641)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)
```

after starting hadoop cluster using this command `start-dfs.sh` my namenode started successfully but datanode did't . when i check datanode log it shows this

```
ToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-06-28 04:01:53,496 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: Master/192.168.0.126:9000. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-06-28 04:01:54,498 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: Master/192.168.0.126:9000. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-06-28 04:01:55,499 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: Master/192.168.0.126:9000. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-06-28 04:01:56,500 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: Master/192.168.0.126:9000. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

i googled but not found solution for this .

when i hit jps command on slave node there it is showing datanode only

and one thing more when i paste 'Master:50070' into browser and Browse file system 
it shows me this error

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /nn_browsedfscontent.jsp. Reason:

    Can't browse the DFS since there are no live nodes available to redirect to.
Caused by:

java.io.IOException: Can't browse the DFS since there are no live nodes available to redirect to.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NamenodeJspHelper.redirectToRandomDataNode(NamenodeJspHelper.java:666)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.nn_005fbrowsedfscontent_jsp._jspService(nn_005fbrowsedfscontent_jsp.java:70)
```

My hadoop cluster configuration is like this

1) /etc/host file on master

[image]

2) /etc/hosts file on slave 
[image]

i have edit entry in master and slave file in hadoop configuration folder i.e masters file i added Master and slaves file i added Slave1

Can anybody help me to solve these problems!

datanode logs showing in two pictures

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post your `datanode` log.

Comment: i have posted already datanode logs above where it is showing Retrying connection...

Comment: hi @Rajesh N i have added snapshots of datanode logs

Comment: Comment `127.0.1.1` line in both master and slave node's `/etc/hosts` file and try restarting hadoop.

Comment: thanks for replying @RajeshN but your solution gives me 'java.net.UnknownHostException: ubuntu: ubuntu
'

Comment: Add `ubuntu` in `/etc/hosts` like this: `192.168.1.100    Master    ubuntu`. Do this on both master and slave node.

Answer (score 0):

Do you config the ssh? Try you use ssh to login the other node to check the ssh connection.

Comment: yes @gwgyk i am able to ssh from one machin to another

Comment: hi @gwgyk i am able to ssh from master to slave machine but not able to do the same from slave to master it is giving me 'ssh: connect to host master port 22: Network is unreachable
'

Comment: Do you append the public key of other nodes to the authorized_keys file of slave node? You should learn about how to config ssh.